# How to Push formGroup in a formArray in Angular 14?

Tags: angular, formarray, formgroups

I am trying to push formgroup in an formArray but it is giving me the error code which is

Argument of type 'FormGroup<{ name: FormControl<string | null>; amount: FormControl<number | null>; }>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.ts(2345)"

Here is how i declared the Array

**let recipeIngredients = new FormArray([]);**

Initializing the form here

```
private initForm() {
    let recipeName = '';
    let recipeImagePath = '';
    let recipeDescription = '';
    let recipeIngredients = new FormArray([]);
    

    if (this.editMode) {
      //getting the recipe
      const recipe = this.recipeService.getRecipe(this.id);
      //assigning the values coming from recipes
      recipeName = recipe.name;
      recipeImagePath = recipe.imagePath;
      recipeDescription = recipe.description;
      if(recipe['_ingredients']){
        for( let ingredient of recipe.ingredients){
          

          recipeIngredients.push( // getting error here
            new FormGroup({
              'name': new FormControl(ingredient.name),
              'amount': new FormControl(ingredient.amount)
            })
          )
          
        }
      }

      this.recipeForm = new FormGroup({
        'name': new FormControl(recipeName),
        'imagePath': new FormControl(recipeImagePath),
        'description': new FormControl(recipeDescription)
        //'ingredients': recipeIngredients

      });
      
    }
```

Comment: How does error change when you go `let recipeIngredients: FormArray = new FormArray([]);`

Comment: @AndrewAllen it says 
Type 'FormArray<never>' is not assignable to type 'FormArray<any>'.
 Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'

Comment: Typescript thinks `[]` inside `FormArray([]);` is of type `never[]`. Try `let recipeIngredients: FormArray = new FormArray<any>([]);`

Comment: Are you on Angular 14, if so I'll post a fuller answer on how to correctly type these things

Comment: yes i am using Angular 14 @AndrewAllen

Answer (score 2):

specify the type of the FormArray

```
items = new FormArray<FormGroup>([]);
```